# WPF treeview items clear

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I am working with WPF `TreeView`. I have bound the `TreeView` with it's `DataContext` property. But whenever I am trying to refresh the `TreeView` by clearing all the nodes, it's not allowing. I have tried

`treeview1.Items.Clear();`

but it throws exception.

Please suggest me how can I solve this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not allowing"?

Comment: it throws exception, can't clear the items

Answer (score 1):

Because you bound the `TreeView` to a collection, in your case you need to set the `DataContext` property to null or an empty collection. Any similar manipulations should be done with your `ObservableCollection` and not directly with `TreeView`.